# UITextField does not interact with user when added to a clipped view area

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitextfield

I created a UIView with an outlet named `_waypointSubview` inside a UIScrollView, which is also inside another UIView, and all 3 were created in my storyboard. From here I am adding UITextFields programmatically, and once there are over 5 UITextFields added it is clipped from the UIScrollView. The UIScrollView and the `_waypointSubview` are then resized to compensate for the extra UITextField added. The user can then scroll down to see all the UITextFields that were clipped from the view. Only the UITextFields that were clipped do not allow editing. I am not sure why that is. So if I add 10 of them, I cannot edit 6 thru 10. I tried programmatically telling it to enable user interaction using the call `[waypointTextField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`but it did not work.

[image]

Can someone please explain why I cannot edit those fields? Thank you.

```
- (IBAction)addWaypoint:(id)sender {

UITextField *waypointTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xCord, yCord, 250, 40)];
waypointTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
waypointTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
waypointTextField.placeholder = @"enter waypoint";
waypointTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
waypointTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
waypointTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
waypointTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
waypointTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
waypointTextField.delegate = self;
[_waypointSubview addSubview:waypointTextField];

UITextField *commentTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xCord + 300, yCord, 380, 40)];
commentTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
commentTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
commentTextField.placeholder = @"enter comment";
commentTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
commentTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
commentTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
commentTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
commentTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
commentTextField.delegate = self;
[_waypointSubview addSubview:commentTextField];

// if waypointArray is not initialized yet, create and add textfield
if (waypointArray == nil) {
    waypointArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
    [waypointArray insertObject:waypointTextField atIndex:0];
    commentArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
    [commentArray insertObject:commentTextField atIndex:0];
}
else{
    // check amount of space left in scroll view, and adjust if needed
    if ([waypointArray count] > 4) {
        self.waypointScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(708, 255 + (([waypointArray count] - 4)*50));
        CGRect frame = self.waypointSubview.frame;
        frame.size.height += 50;
        self.waypointSubview.frame = frame;
        //[waypointTextField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }
    // add new text fields to corresponding arrays
    [waypointArray addObject:waypointTextField];
    [commentArray addObject:commentTextField];
}
yCord += 50; // update the yCoordinate that will be used for the next textField placement
}
```

Comment: Did you connect _waypointSubview to your view controller in storyboard?

Comment: I did not. How would you go about that? Thanks.

Comment: :) appreciated now i think it would work fine,

Comment: I added a screenshot above to show what I think you're referring to. It was already connected.

Comment: Are you sure that the text fields are still inside the bounds of waypointSubview? Try giving that view a background color to check that. The most common reason for unresponsive controls is that they lie outside the bounds of their superview.

Comment: Good idea. I see what is going on now. When it resizes my _waypointSubview it is only temporary and it only works if it is in the bounds of _waypointSuperview. So what I did was ditch _waypointSubview all together and add my UITextFields to the UIScrollView. It is working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need to connect _waypointSubview to the view controller on your storyboard by just reading the comments. 
In order to do that

1. Right click on the the view controller icon on the storyboard view controller
2. Click and drag the little circle to the object you are trying to edit or the method you're trying to implement from the IBAction.

Comment: Okay maybe I just didn't understand what Light Yagami was asking at first. I did already have _waypointSubview connected to the storyboard, so when you see '@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *waypointSubview;' the circle on the left to it is filled, and not blank.

Answer (score 0):

Check your bounds of your textfield as -

```
UITextField *commentTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xCord + 300, yCord, 380, 40)];
```

Here if you observe the xcordinate, an Iphone has a width of 320points. 
If your textfield is 380points wide then how can you accomodate it WHEN its (0,0) is starting from xCord(I dont know what is its value) + 300.

Lower the xcordinate value and color its background, to check whether it falls in bounds as pointed out by @rdelmar